# Custom control with TextBox and Button does not inherit styles from parent

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I created a user control with a TextBox and a Button, but it does not want to use the parent's style. However, my control appeas to have the parent's style at design time, but at runtime the styles disappear.

There is my TextBoxButton.xaml

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type Common:TextBoxExtension}" TargetType="{x:Type Common:TextBoxExtension}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Common:TextBoxExtension}">
                <Border x:Name="border" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Padding="-3.0" Margin="2"
                                Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBoxBase},Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                Content="..."
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"/>
                        <ScrollViewer Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Also, there is TextBoxExtension.cs

```
public class TextBoxExtension : TextBox
{
    static TextBoxExtension()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBoxExtension), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextBoxExtension)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(TextBoxExtension), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Usage in window

```
<Common:TextBoxExtension FontSize="14" Text="{Binding VaultPath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
<Common:TextBoxExtension FontSize="14" Command="{Binding SetLocalPath}" Text="{Binding LocalPath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
```

What i expected to get

[image: ExpectedImage]

What i get when run the program

[image: RealResults]

Want to add that buttons is working

Comment: What does "parents style" mean? Are you talking about the style of the `Border`, white background and gray BorderBrush?

Comment: Yeah
`  `  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"`

I think, this must get styles from TextBox, but it don't

Comment: And you have another style somewhere that's setting those?

Comment: No, i dont have any another style

Comment: If you want default values for BorderBrush and BorderThickness, you should add setters for those properties to the default style. I don't know why you'd be seeing anything for those in the designer.

Comment: I don't need default values in setter, i already fix this problem, but in wrong way, i just added properties that i need in <Common:TextBoxExtension/>

Comment: You should have default values in setters in the style, unless the desired default appearance is for the borders not to be visible, as in your second screenshot. What question are you asking here?

Comment: But this must works another way : TextBoxExtension.Styles + Button > TextBox.Styles.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not clear, i was trying to figure out whats the problem all day

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Something must be wrong in your program. What is wrong in your program?

Comment: Can't replicate your issue when pasting the code works fine. Maybe try 

`<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"></Setter>` in your style

Comment: I tried this, and that does not work for me(